# References and updates on a $L^p$ Factorization theorem by Maurey

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

In the "Exposé XV" of the 1972-1973 of the Maurey-Schwartz Seminar of functional analysis ("Théorèmes de factorisation pour les opérateurs linéaires à
valeurs dans un espace $L^p(\Omega, \mu)$, $0<p \leq \infty$"), which can be found in French at http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=SAF_1972-1973____A14_0 the following result appears

#### Corollary

Let $0<p\leq q \leq s$ and $r^{-1}=p ^{-1}- q^{-1}$. Assume that $0<p \leq q \leq 2 \leq s < \infty$. Then, any bounded operator $u:L^s_\nu \rightarrow L^p_\mu$ factorizes as $u=T_f \circ v$, with $v:L^s_\nu \rightarrow L^q_\mu$ and $T_f$ the multiplication by a function $f\in L^r_\mu$.

I would like to know whether there are any recent surveys or articles where this or similar results are discussed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned in another of your posts the book of Diestel, Jarchow,and Tonge. Chapter 7 in the book of Albiac and Kalton, "Topics in Banach space theory", contains a nice exposition of Maurey's theorem and related topics.

Pisier proved and used non commutative factorization theorems, in case you are interested in non commutative $L_p$ spaces.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I will check it out. Do you happen to know whether there are results for some specific operators like the Fourier transform?